# How to compare Unicode strings so that strings that LOOK the same compare equally?

Tags: unicode

Many sequences of encoded Unicode characters have the same visual representation and the same computational meaning.

The ñ character can be coded two ways:

```
U+00F1:  ñ   (LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TIDLE)
```

or:

```
U+006E:  n   (LATIN SMALL LETTER N)
U+0303:  ~   (COMBINING TILDE)
```

This creates 10 different byte sequences that display as ñ:

```
U+00F1 in UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32BE, UTF32-LE 
U+006E followed by U+0303  UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32BE, UTF32-LE
```

Is there any straightforward way to compare Unicode strings (I'm happy with unicode characters that have been decoded from the various UTF representations) and find out that they are the same?   That is, I want something that tells me that U+00F1 is the same as U+0303 U+006E

Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you're not also asking about distinct characters that happen to look the same, like hyphen vs. en-dash; that's likely to be a much harder problem.

Comment: Oh, that's my next question! (just kidding). yes, I know it's a much harder problem. You've basically got to render the text and do image processing.

Comment: See the excellent answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841290/do-latin-capital-letter-i-u0049-and-roman-numeral-one-u2160-have-unicode-c/8841591#8841591

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is called *normalization*, supported by any decent Unicode library.  Backgrounder [is here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).